# A collection of stories of witches

Tags: story-identification, books, anthology-book, witches, illustrated-story

I'm looking for a book that has a collection of stories about witches. I'm not sure if it is a collection of short stories and also is illustrated.

I'm not sure it's for kids or young adults because I was very young at that time and could barely read. I found this book in a bookstore on the front display but I didn't get it because my mother didn't like it.

All I vaguely remember is the book cover and the one of the story ending. The book cover has one of the witches facing you and the story is about the character's sister or friend turning into a tiny wood sculpture. I'm not sure if the stories are an arc or separate but they're all about witches

Comment: What year and what country was this in?

Comment: Philippines but is english Edit: i forget how i old was i but i was still is grade school

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, when were you in grade school?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh my gosh, I actually found it: ***[The Big Book of Witches](https://preciousshop.com.ph/products/lampara-books/the-big-book-of-witches/)***.

> Discover a world reigned over by 13 of countless WITCHES featured in history, legends and fairy tales. It is an kingdom of evil, of
> darkness, which will leave you wanting to read more and more.
>
> Read about witches from fairy tales such as The Gingerbread House,
> Frau Trude and Legends such as Baba Yaga from Russia, Ceridwen from
> Great Britain, the Witch who Wore Painted Skins from China, Cloantsa
> from Romania, the Witch of the Rose Bush from Brazil, one of the Salem
> witches and the Bell Witch from the United States and Others from
> France.